# AnythingSlider cross-fade not working

Tags: jquery, fade, anythingslider

I'm using AnythingSlider for a client site.  The latest version of Anything Slider (1.8.x) supposedly will now cross-fade the slides.  But for some reason it's just not working.  It still does what the older versions did: fade out a slide, then new slide pops up.  Very frustrating.  I'm guessing that it must just be some setting I have incorrect, but for the life of me I can't tell what.  Hair. Pulled. Out.

My initialization code is:

```
    $('#slider').anythingSlider({
    mode                : 'fade',
    resizeContents      : false,
    delay               : 6000, 
    resumeDelay         : 5000,
    navigationSize      : 5,
    buildStartStop      : false,
    hashTags            : false,
    autoPlay            : true
    });
```

You can take a look at the testing site here:  http://mlkchapel.dandelion-patch.com/test.html

Any thoughts on why the cross-fade isn't working? I appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar [issue](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/issues/447) was reported at the github repository. Basically this problem appears when the slider is wrapped in positioned (relative or absolute) elements with a background color/image.

Just change these two lines in the css to fix it.

```
.anythingSlider .fade .activePage { z-index: 1; }
.anythingSlider .fade .panel { z-index: 0; }
```

The `.panel` previously was set with a `-1` z-index.